# About interparticular distance and thermal de Broglie wavelength

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, particle-physics

The interparticular distance $d$ in a gas is correlated with thermal de Broglie wavelength $\lambda_B$. This relation defines when consider quatum effects or classical behavior:
if $d \leq \lambda_B$, quatum effects are considered, and if $d >> \lambda_B$, the system is studied classically.
My questions are:
What if $d$ is greater than $\lambda_B$ but not necessarily much greater?
In this interval, what is the behavior of the particle?

Comment: Sorry, *quantum

Comment: You can use the quantum solution generally. It works for all $d$, not just when $d\leqslant\lambda_B$. It just so happens that only in the case of $d\gg\lambda_B$ that we can use the classical approximation. (Actually, there will be corrections due to the fact that no real material is an ideal gas. We would then need to correct for interparticle interactions.)

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent, how many orders $d$ must be much greater than $\lambda_B$?

Comment: How precise do you need your answers to?